# Is there a way to check if the debugger is attached in React-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, mobile, react-native

Title says it all really. Is there a way to check if the debugger (in the browser) is attached or not?

Comment: Do you mean in the actual RN app, via code or from the emulator / browser tab?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about doing this in code. Similar to how it is possible to detect the platform or if the app is being run from a simulator.